# Error in reading data with pymodbus

Tags: raspbian, python, modbus

I have been trying to read data from a modbus slave device using pymodbus. After much research I found this code on internet. It is a straight forward code. I am able to read the data on windows but RPi returns "none". There have been similar questions on this site but none of them seem to have been answered.

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient
#def checkProxCounter():
count = 0
result = 0

#UART.setup("UART1")
client = ModbusClient(method='rtu',port='/dev/ttyUSB1',parity= 'E',stopbits=1,bytesize=8,baudrate=19200,timeout=3)

try:
  if client.connect():
      print ("Port open")
      result = client.read_holding_registers(address=3909, count=2,unit=1)
      print ("Result : ")
      print (result)
      blah = client.read_discrete_inputs(1,8)

      if blah != None:
          print("{}: {}".format("Blah", blah.bits[0]))

      if result != None:
          count = int(str(result.registers[0]),16) + int(str(result.registers[1]),16)
          print("{}: {}".format("Count", count))
      else:
          print("results were none")
      client.close()
  else:
      print("Port failed to open")
      count = -2

except:
  print("Unknown Exception")
  raise

print count
```

Comment: What modbus adapter are you using with your Pi?

Comment: @jwygralak67 I am using "qinheng electronics hl-340 usb-serial adapter"

Comment: Is this the same adapter you used successfully with windows? Did you run the same python program on windows, or did you use a different software?

Comment: @jwygralak67 The adapter is the same that I used on Windows but, I used visual studio and nmodbus library there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so turns out that the adapter "QinHeng Electronics HL-340 usb-serial" does not work with Linux. I bought a new adapter with an original FTDI chip and all the codes worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. I found, that HL-340 with pymodbus on Pi sent data with parity NONE, even with EVEN configuration. When I changed parity to NONE, it worked.

```
#UART.setup("UART1")
client = ModbusClient(method='rtu',port='/dev/ttyUSB1',parity= 'N',stopbits=1,bytesize=8,baudrate=19200,timeout=3)
```

Bug in HL-340 driver?

Comment: I think parity and stop bits need to match with the settings of the client device. It seems that the original FTDI chip driven modbus converters work well with Linux. I couldn't find any driver for HL-340 that worked on Linux.