# Reading registers through pymodbus

Tags: raspbian, python, modbus

I have been trying to use pymodbus to read registers from a power meter and searching around here I found a useful code from the question I attach in the end of this post. So I wrote/copied the next code:

```
import pymodbus
import serial
from pymodbus.pdu import ModbusRequest
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient 
#initialize a serial RTU client instance
from pymodbus.transaction import ModbusRtuFramer

#def checkProxCounter():
count = 0
result = 0

#UART.setup("UART1")
client = ModbusClient(method='rtu',port='/dev/ttyUSB0',parity='N',stopbits=1,bytesize=8,baudrate=9600,timeout=3)

try:
  if client.connect():
  print ("Port open")
  result = client.read_holding_registers(address=0x00, count=2,unit=0x01)
  print ("Result : ")
  print (result)
  blah = client.read_discrete_inputs(1,8)

  if blah != None:
      print("{}: {}".format("Blah", blah.bits[0]))

  if result != None:
      count = int(str(result.registers[0]),16) + int(str(result.registers[1]),16)
      print("{}: {}".format("Count", count))
  else:
      print("results were none")
  client.close()
else:
  print("Port failed to open")
  count = -2

except:
  print("Unknown Exception")
  raise

print count
```

When I try to run it the next Output appears:

```
Port Open
Result:
ReadRegisterResponse(2)
Unknown Exception
Traceback(most recent call last):
  File"prueba2.py", line 30, in <module>
    count = int(str(result.registers[0]),16) + int(str(result.registers[1]),16)
AttributeError:'ReadHoldingRegistersResponse' object has no attribute 'register'
```

Obviously there is something wrong or missing here but I am still a beginner programming and I don't see it.
I understand that the variable "count" is changing the register to an integer.
And to be honest I don't know what is exactly doing the variable "blah" nor the code printed as "{}: {}".format(   )  .

Any advice or way to fix this problem?

[Error in reading data with pymodbus](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40334/error-in-reading-data-with-pymodbus)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that by adding `print result.registers`, I could obtain the data.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.